# Is there a vectorized implementation to refer to a value in the previous value in a time series?

Tags: r, time-series

I've seen threads saying there isn't (without looping) and those that seem to get it to work, which I can't as of yet apply.

Here is my data. The 3rd column is what I seek. It represents investment returns by month. I'd like to calculate a hypothetical initial investment of 10,000, multiply that by 1.10 (the first amount), then multiply that result by 1.4 for the second, etc. Note that the first calculation is just the series value x 10,000 and all subsequent values are dependent on the prior.

```
1/1/2000    .10    11,000
2/1/2000    .40    15,400
3/1/2000    .20    18,480
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `cumprod` (for arithmetic returns) or `cumsum` (for log returns)

```
cumprod(1+c(0.10, 0.40, 0.20)) * 10000
cumsum(1+c(0.10, 0.40, 0.20)) * 10000
```